# Как скачать zip архив с удаленного сервера

Tags: php, curl

Я делаю так:

```
    set_time_limit(0); // указываем, чтобы скрипт не ограничивался временем по умолчанию
    ignore_user_abort(1); // указываем, чтобы скрипт продолжал работать даже при разрыве
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/geo.zip';
    $url = 'http://ipgeobase.ru/files/db/Main/geo_files.zip';
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w+');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Устанавливаем параметр, чтобы curl возвращал данные, вместо того, чтобы выводить их в браузер.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Но архива в корне сайта нет.
Соединение с файлом есть, так как если убрать строку

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

то появляются кракозябры

Comment: Если вы хотите получать результат выполнения curl, то нужно результат положить в переменную (`$response = curl_exec($ch);`) и далее обработать его, сохранить например.

Comment: а CURLOPT_FILE не сохранят в файл?

Comment: да, не досмотрел) но чесно, не уверен в одновременном использовании двух параметров, по описанию они взаимоисключающие друг друга, ну и плюс  CURLOPT_FILE запишет любой ответ, а это может быть ошибка а не сам файл, что не очень хорошо. в любом случае вам дали решение

Answer (score 2):

Решение через `copy`

```
<?php
copy('http://ipgeobase.ru/files/db/Main/geo_files.zip', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/geo.zip');
```

Решение через `file_put_contents`

```
<?php
file_put_contents(
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/geo.zip',
    file_get_contents('http://ipgeobase.ru/files/db/Main/geo_files.zip')
);
```

Comment: у меня обе ф-ии возвращают false ((

Comment: вам необходимо включить `allow_url_fopen` в `php.ini` http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: включен. и даже макс. размер скачиваемых файлов увеличил, но все равно false (

Comment: Дело было в отсутствии прав на r+w Для apache ) сие права стояли только на мне :)